# Can't save multiple FuncAnimation as a single gif in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, 3d

I'm trying to make a 3D animation in matplotlib and I want my plots combined together but I can't save it as a gif file. I have made two different plots but I cant save them in one file. What should I do?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d as p3
import matplotlib.animation as animation


fig = plt.figure()
ax = p3.Axes3D(fig)

def gen(n):
    z = 0
    while z < 10:
        yield np.array([0, 10 * np.cos((-18 * np.pi * z) + (2 * np.pi / 3)), z])
        z += 10 / n

def gen1(m):
    z = 0
    while z < 10:
        yield np.array([-5 * np.cos((-18 * np.pi * z) + (2 * np.pi / 3)), 0, z])
        z += 10 / m

def update(num, data, line):
    line.set_data(data[:2, :num])
    line.set_3d_properties(data[2, :num])

N = 100
data = np.array(list(gen(N))).T
line, = ax.plot(data[0, 0:1], data[1, 0:1], data[2, 0:1])

M = 100
data1 = np.array(list(gen1(M))).T
line1, = ax.plot(data1[0, 0:1], data1[1, 0:1], data1[2, 0:1])

# Setting the axes properties
ax.set_xlim3d([-10.0, 10.0])
ax.set_xlabel('X')

ax.set_ylim3d([-10.0, 10.0])
ax.set_ylabel('Y')

ax.set_zlim3d([0.0, 10.0])
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, N, fargs=(data, line), interval=8000/N, blit=False), animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, M, fargs=(data1, line1), interval=8000/N, blit=False)
# ani1 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, M, fargs=(data1, line1), interval=8000/N, blit=False)
ani.save('FlatWave.gif', writer='imagemagick')
```

The error is that its due to `ani` object that is a tuple, but I couldn't find anyway to combine plots together. Thanks!

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'save'
```

Comment: It says you're calling `save` on a tuple. Check what is returned from `FuncAnimation`. `ani` seems to be a tuple so what you need might be in one of its elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have only `FuncAnimation` object that animates all the artists.

for instance:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d as p3
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax = p3.Axes3D(fig)

def gen(n):
    z = 0
    while z < 10:
        yield np.array([0, 10 * np.cos((-18 * np.pi * z) + (2 * np.pi / 3)), z])
        z += 10 / n

def gen1(m):
    z = 0
    while z < 10:
        yield np.array([-5 * np.cos((-18 * np.pi * z) + (2 * np.pi / 3)), 0, z])
        z += 10 / m

def update(num, data, line):
    line.set_data(data[:2, :num])
    line.set_3d_properties(data[2, :num])

def update_both(num, data1, line1, data2, line2):
    update(num, data1, line1)
    update(num, data2, line2)

N = 100
data = np.array(list(gen(N))).T
line, = ax.plot(data[0, 0:1], data[1, 0:1], data[2, 0:1])

M = 100
data1 = np.array(list(gen1(M))).T
line1, = ax.plot(data1[0, 0:1], data1[1, 0:1], data1[2, 0:1])

# Setting the axes properties
ax.set_xlim3d([-10.0, 10.0])
ax.set_xlabel('X')

ax.set_ylim3d([-10.0, 10.0])
ax.set_ylabel('Y')

ax.set_zlim3d([0.0, 10.0])
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_both, N, fargs=(data, line, data1, line1), interval=8000/N, blit=False)
ani.save('FlatWave.gif', writer='imagemagick')
```

Comment: You're welcome. If your problem is solved, consider accepting the answer using the checkmark on the left to close the topic